# How to import CSV file into an docker postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker postgres image running, which I am building via the Dockerfile. In the Dockerfile I am copying my CSV which is located into the /data directory into /data/ in the docker machine. Like this :

```
    COPY /data/* /data/
```

I am also copying my sql file into the docker entrypoint so it will be executed on container boot.
Now here comes the problem. In the proeve_schema.sql I am creating an table:

```
    CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
      ORDERDATE      TEXT,
      CASETYPE       TEXT,
      CASEID         TEXT,
    );
```

And I am trying to copy the data from my CSV into the table:

```
    COPY sample_data
    FROM '/data/bom_sampledata_1000.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

However, when I try to run my container it crashed without any errorlog.
When I remove the COPY statement it runs well and my table is generated.
Also, the CSV file is present on the container.

Dockerfile:

````
    RUN mkdir -p /data
    #copy all data to the container 
    COPY /data/* /data/
    COPY proeve_schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/```
    RUN chown postgres /data
    RUN chmod +w /data
````

proeve_schema.sql:

````
    CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
      ORDERDATE      TEXT,
      CASETYPE       TEXT,
      CASEID         TEXT,
      CUSTOMERNUMBER TEXT,
    );

    COPY sample_data
    FROM '/data/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;```
````

Comment: Have you tried `docker logs <dead container name>`?

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it. Turns out i had the ID field not in my csv..... Now it works. Dumb dumb dumb.....